# Remove gap at top and bottom of <a>

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` inside of a table that fills the `<td>` (its parent)

The `<div>` contains one `<a>`

What i would like to do is give the `<a>`s 100% height and width

[image]

That is from hovering over the item in the inspect element menu.

So I have no idea how to make it have a width and the height of the container

I have tried

```css
height:100%;
width:100%;
```

But still no luck and nothing has changed

Comment: Did you check for padding in addition to border and margin?

Comment: @KyleWillmon I have checked

Comment: @e102 After your edit, the issue seems to be that an `a` with its default `display: inline` does not respond to `width` or `height` properties. Change the display to `inline-block` or `block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just style your "a" tag with *display:block* in CSS.